# Positioning whole elements side by side

Tags: css

I have some DIVs with contents inside. I want to display them side by side and if there is no space, I want to break the whole div, so the contents don't go to a new line alone.

I've made [this example of what happens](http://jsfiddle.net/qB225/).

Here is a screenshot from the link above.

[csspos http://img709.imageshack.us/img709/6799/csswo.png](http://img709.imageshack.us/img709/6799/csswo.png)

And here is the expected output

[cssposright http://img826.imageshack.us/img826/8530/csse.png](http://img826.imageshack.us/img826/8530/csse.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about http://jsfiddle.net/qB225/15/? That adds

```
.item {
    ...
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: I'm seeing 3 links on the first row, then 1 on the second row.

Comment: That's possible. The question was, however, not to equally distribute these texts. The question was about wrapping.

Comment: Agreed. That's another question, and the user doesn't specify whether he wants `overflow: auto` or `overflow: none`.

Answer (score 1):

Put non-breaking space between your links and spans.

http://jsfiddle.net/qB225/22/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/qB225/21/

```
.master
{
    width: 160px;
}

.item
{
    display:inline-block;
    font-size: 11px;
    padding: 2px 2px 2px 0;
}

.item { display:inline; } /* DO NOT REMOVE, FOR IE */

.item a
{
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
​
```

Comment: Change the right padding to 12 and you will see it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want them to only wrap as pairs you need to do two things.  First change your html so that you group your item divs in pairs of two:

```
<div class="master">
    <div>
        <div class="item">
            <a href="javascript:;">Text</a>
            <span>(10)</span>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <a href="javascript:;">Text</a>
            <span>(10)</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="item">
            <a href="javascript:;">Text</a>
            <span>(10)</span>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <a href="javascript:;">Text</a>
            <span>(10)</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then add a float to the grouping divs:

```
.master > div{ float:left; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using "inline-block" as follows:

```
.item
{
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 11px;
  padding: 2px 2px 2px 0;
}
```

Thanks.